# How to run a build angular 4 project on apache cordova

Tags: javascript, android, angular, cordova

I build a simple angular 4 project with `ng build` and copied the contents to my cordova's project `www` folder. The cordova project runs ok on a browser - `cordova run browser` but it can't run on android - `cordova run android`. It only shows the contents of `index.html` but can't load the `app.component` component. How can I make it run on android? Thanks.

Comment: Are you getting any errors on the console? You can debug WebViews on Android devices with Chrome via `chrome://inspect`

Comment: Mmmh never used it before. Could you please guide me on how to use that? @DarthJDG

Comment: If you run your cordova app (cordova run android) on emulator or device connected with usb then go to your chrome browser and (url:chrome://inspect) you will see on list your connected device or emulator and click inspect of your running application. More info here: https://gonzalo123.com/2014/08/04/debugging-android-cordovaphonegap-apps-with-chrome/